# Next.js building in container, all .env variables which not starting with NEXT_PUBLIC_ are undefined (on the server side)

Tags: docker, next.js, github-actions

I have a Next.js app that works locally (yarn dev) using .env.local for secret vars and all working fine.

When I deploy my app to a server in a Docker container, with GitHub Actions, while creating the .env file on the fly, it appears that only variables that start with NEXT_PUBLIC_ are actually defined as normal, other variables are undefined when I console.log and check in the **server **(container) logs.

So the client side env vars are fine, server side are undefined.

Here is my GitHub Actions yml that creates the .env file:

```
jobs:
  build_and_push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Make envfile
        uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.3
        with:
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_EXPIRATION: ${{ vars.NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_EXPIRATION }}
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET: ${{ vars.NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET }}
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_SECRET: ${{ vars.NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_SECRET }}
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL: ${{ vars.DEV_API_BASE_URL }}
          envkey_MONGO_DB_URI: ${{ secrets.DEV_MONGO_DB_URI }}
          envkey_WEATHER_DB: ${{ vars.DEV_WEATHER_DB }}
          envkey_WILLI_WEATHER_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.WILLI_WEATHER_API_KEY }}
          file_name: .env
          fail_on_empty: false

      - name: Build container image
        run: docker build -t $(echo $REGISTRY)/$(echo $IMAGE_NAME):$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | head -c7) .

      - name: Install doctl
        uses: digitalocean/action-doctl@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

      - name: Log in to DigitalOcean Container Registry with short-lived credentials
        run: doctl registry login --expiry-seconds 600

      - name: Remove all old images
        run: if [ ! -z "$(doctl registry repository list | grep "$(echo $IMAGE_NAME)")" ]; then doctl registry repository delete-manifest $(echo $IMAGE_NAME) $(doctl registry repository list-tags $(echo $IMAGE_NAME) | grep -o "sha.*") --force; else echo "No repository"; fi

      - name: Push image to DigitalOcean Container Registry
        run: docker push --max-concurrent-uploads 1 $(echo $REGISTRY)/$(echo $IMAGE_NAME):$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | head -c7)

      - name: Run registry garbage collection
        run: doctl registry garbage-collection start --include-untagged-manifests --force
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as dependencies
WORKDIR /my-project
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
    
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

FROM node:16-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /my-project
COPY . .
COPY --from=dependencies /my-project/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY ./.env ./node_modules/.env
RUN yarn build

FROM node:16-alpine as runner
WORKDIR /my-project
ENV NODE_ENV production

# If you are using a custom next.config.js file, uncomment this line.
# COPY --from=builder /my-project/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /my-project/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /my-project/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /my-project/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /my-project/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /my-project/_fonts /usr/local/share/fonts
COPY --from=builder /my-project/_assets ./_assets

#install fontconfig and clear cache
RUN apk add --update fontconfig 
RUN fc-cache -f -v

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

In the Docker file, I copy the .env file into the node_modules folder to make sure that this file is created correctly. And I can verify that all variables with and without NEXT_PUBLIC_ are having values as in my original .env.local file.

Here is an output of my log from the container which was triggered on a specific endpoint request:

```
### Response start here:                                                                                                                                                                    
Timestamp:  5/21/23, 9:39 AM                                                                                                                                                                
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL http://10.0.4.6:3000/                                                                                                                                              
MONGO_DB_URI undefined                                                                                                                                                                      
WEATHER_DB undefined                                                                                                                                                                        
WILLI_WEATHER_API_KEY undefined                                                                                                                                                            
NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_EXPIRATION 5m                                                                                                                                                              
NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET 7c4c1c50-3230-45bf-9eae-c9b2e401c767                                                                                                                  
NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_SECRET dd5f3089-40c3-403d-af14-d0c228b05cb4                                                                                                                                
Delta time =  142392
```

Here is the output of the .env file I copied when the Docker image was built (I modified sensitive data):

```
/my-project/node_modules # cat .env                                                                                                                                                        
MONGO_DB_URI=mongodb+srv://mame:reJHeDc@maev.v8ilhrq.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority                                                                
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=http://10.0.4.6:3000/                                                                                                                                              
NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_EXPIRATION=5m                                                                                                                                                              
NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET=7c4c1c50-3230-45bf-9eae-c9b2e401c767                                                                                                                  
NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_SECRET=dd5f3089-40c3-403d-af14-d0c228b05cb4                                                                                                                                
WEATHER_DB=Weather                                                                                                                                                                          
WILLI_WEATHER_API_KEY=YjQ3MDkwMGDkN2VjQ3MDkwMGZjjOD
```

(I modified sensitive data)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add to your question what you have tried so far to resolve your issue. Additionally the concrete command line is missing how you are trying to verify the results (both the command as well as the output showing _how_ you validate the server (container) environment.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a variable like `WILLI_WEATHER_API_KEY` is visible and defines when Docker is built.
But not when the application is *run*.

Meaning: the issue should be linked to how Next.js loads environment variables.
[Environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables) are loaded into the Next.js application at build time, not at runtime, which means that any changes to the environment variables after the build process won't be reflected in the running application.

In your case, you are correctly creating a `.env` file with all your environment variables, but by the time this file is created and placed into the `node_modules` directory, the Next.js application has already been built, and it's too late for these variables to be incorporated.

Next.js has a specific way of handling environment variables:

- If you prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`, it will be available on both the server and client side.
- If it doesn't start with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`, it will only be available on the server side.

Additionally, these variables need to be available at build time, not runtime. This means that you must provide these variables before the `yarn build` command is run.
In your case, the `.env` file is generated and copied during the Docker build process, which is after the Next.js build process; hence they are inaccessible.

To solve this issue, you need to ensure that your environment variables are available before the `yarn build` command is run.

Your Dockerfile would then be:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as dependencies
WORKDIR /my-project
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
    
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

FROM node:16-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /my-project
COPY . .
COPY --from=dependencies /my-project/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY ./.env ./.env  # copy the .env file to the root of the project
RUN yarn build

FROM node:16-alpine as runner
WORKDIR /my-project
ENV NODE_ENV production

# If you are using a custom next.config.js file, uncomment this line.
# COPY --from=builder /my-project/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /my-project/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /my-project/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /my-project/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /my-project/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /my-project/_fonts /usr/local/share/fonts
COPY --from=builder /my-project/_assets ./_assets
COPY --from=builder /my-project/.env ./.env  # this is probably not necessary for runtime, but does not hurt

#install fontconfig and clear cache
RUN apk add --update fontconfig 
RUN fc-cache -f -v

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

You should make sure not to expose sensitive data in your logs or Docker image for security reasons.
Using secrets management systems or environment variable injection at runtime (for non-Next.js variables) would be a more secure approach.

---

> "What I understand from you is that if we don't provide the env variables in our files but from the Cloud Provider App Settings (Azure), the container cannot access them after the build time, right?

True: when using Next.js, environment variables are embedded into the build at the time the application is compiled. That means if you are relying on environment variables provided by a cloud provider's runtime environment (such as Azure App Settings), those variables will not be accessible to your application after the build process if they were not available at build time.

In the context of deploying a Next.js application in a containerized environment like Docker, the environment variables need to be defined before or during the build step (`yarn build`). That is important for server-side variables (those not prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`) as they are baked into the server-side code at build time.

For client-side accessible variables (prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`), although they are also embedded at build time, they are less of a concern since their main use case is within the browser, where they can be more easily manipulated or substituted.

If you need to use cloud provider runtime environment variables (like Azure App Settings) with a Next.js application running in a container, you have a couple of options:

1. **Build-Time Injection**: Make sure all necessary environment variables are injected into your container at build time. That can be achieved by setting these variables in your CI/CD pipeline or Docker build process before the `yarn build` command is executed.
2. **Runtime Configuration**: For variables that must be configurable at runtime (outside the Next.js built-in support for environment variables), consider implementing a runtime configuration solution. That often involves serving your Next.js application through a custom server (e.g., an Express.js server) that can dynamically read environment variables at runtime and inject them into your application. However, this approach is more complex and may not be suitable for all variables, especially those needed during the Next.js build process.

Remember, directly using runtime environment variables provided by cloud platforms in a Next.js application without making them available at build time will result in them being undefined when your application runs. To circumvent this, you may need to adapt your deployment strategy to make sure all necessary variables are correctly injected at the appropriate stage of your application's lifecycle.

---

> My team lead required me not to define env variables in env files but in `APP SETTINGS` in Azure, but I could not access them in Docker.
> How do I handle this scenario?

If you have to use Azure App Settings for environment variables instead of `.env` files, and you are deploying a Next.js application inside Docker containers, you face the challenge of making these runtime environment variables available at build time inside your Docker container.

#### Approach 1: Azure DevOps Pipeline

If you are using Azure DevOps, you can inject environment variables into your build process directly from Azure App Settings via the pipeline.

First, export your App Settings from Azure to your Azure DevOps pipeline variables. You might need to use the Azure CLI or Azure DevOps tasks to fetch these values and set them as pipeline variables.

Use these pipeline variables to dynamically create a `.env` file or directly inject them into your Docker build process as build arguments.

Example of creating a `.env` file in the pipeline script:

```yaml
steps:
- script: |
    echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=$(NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL)" > .env
    echo "MONGO_DB_URI=$(MONGO_DB_URI)" >> .env
    # Add other variables similarly
  displayName: 'Generate .env file'
```

Then, make sure your Dockerfile copies this `.env` file at build time.

Alternatively, you can pass these variables as build arguments in your Dockerfile. You would need to modify your `docker build` command to include `--build-arg` for each variable and modify your Dockerfile to accept these arguments.

Docker build command example:

```bash
docker build --build-arg NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=$(NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL) --build-arg MONGO_DB_URI=$(MONGO_DB_URI) ...
```

Dockerfile adjustments:

```
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL
ARG MONGO_DB_URI
# Set the environment variables from the arguments
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=$NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL MONGO_DB_URI=$MONGO_DB_URI
```

#### Approach 2: Azure Container Instances (ACI) or Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

If you are deploying to Azure Container Instances or Kubernetes Service, you can utilize the service's capability to inject environment variables at runtime.

When deploying a container, you can specify environment variables directly in the container's settings that are pulled from Azure App Settings.

For AKS, use Kubernetes secrets or ConfigMaps to set environment variables, which can be linked to Azure Key Vault or set manually in the deployment YAML files.

---

> 1. Define the variables in the App Settings.
> 2. Adjust the Docker file as you mentioned.
> 3. Adjust the Azure Pipeline: `arguments: "--build-arg NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=${NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}"`
>
> But it does not work.

The main step is making sure that these App Settings variables are fetched and made available in your Azure DevOps pipeline. That usually involves scripting with Azure CLI to pull these settings into your pipeline variables:

```yaml
steps:
- script: |
    az login --service-principal -u $(AZURE_APP_ID) -p $(AZURE_PASSWORD) --tenant $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)
    mapboxToken=$(az webapp config appsettings list --name <YourAppServiceName> --resource-group <YourResourceGroupName> --query "[?name=='NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'].value" -o tsv)
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN]$mapboxToken"
    echo "Fetched NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN: $mapboxToken"
  displayName: 'Fetch Azure App Settings'
```

That would log into Azure using a Service Principal (you need to define `AZURE_APP_ID`, `AZURE_PASSWORD`, and `AZURE_TENANT_ID` as pipeline variables or use existing ones if they are already defined), fetches the `NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN` from your App Settings, and sets it as a pipeline variable.

After fetching the variables, you can use them in your Docker build step as build arguments, as you have mentioned. However, make sure the variable is correctly referenced and make sure your Dockerfile is set up to accept these build arguments.

To make sure your variables are correctly fetched and available, you can add `echo` commands in your pipeline to print them out (be careful with sensitive data).
The Azure pipeline Docker build step could be:

```yaml
steps:
- script: |
    echo "Using NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN) for Docker build"
    docker build . --file Dockerfile --build-arg NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN) -t yourimage:tag
  displayName: 'Echo Variable and Build Docker Image'
```

And in your Dockerfile:

```
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=$NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The environment variable is passed as a build argument to the Docker build context, and is set as an environment variable inside your Docker image.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried your suggestion, but the result is still the same. Only the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` variables are defined, the rest are showing as undefined when `console.log()`. Also, I don't think there is a need for your line, all files are copied with the `COPY . .`  anyway. The reason I copied it to the `node_module` folder is to verify it was constructed successfully within GitHub Actions. I've added this line for debugging purposes only.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your second comment for the runtime! That solved it!

Comment: @vitallyz Sorry for the late answer, I see you manage to make it work, well done!

Comment: @VonC, thank you for this answer but what I understand from you is that if we don't provide the env variables in our files but from the Cloud Provider App Settings ( Azure ), the container can not access them after the build time,right?

Comment: @VonC, thank you so much, my team lead requires to not define env variables in en files but in APP SETTINGS in Azure, but I could not access them in Docker. How do I handle this scenario?

Comment: Hi @VonC, thank you so much, you mentioned :

First, export your App Settings from Azure to your Azure DevOps pipeline variables. You might need to use the Azure CLI or Azure DevOps tasks to fetch these values and set them as pipeline variables.

However, I did not know the exact way. These are the steps I made:

1. Define the variables in the App Settings.

2. Adjust the Docker file as you mentioned.

3. Adjust the Azure Pipeline:

`arguments: "--build-arg NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=${NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}"`

But it does not work.